# ¿Por qué no me reconoce la librería?

Tags: php

Estoy intentando usar la librería FPDF en PHP, pero no me la reconoce.

```
<?php

    require 'fpdf/fpdf.php';


    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->Cell(40,10,'¡Hola, Mundo!');
    $pdf->Output();
    ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo no veo la carpeta `fpdf` en tu explorador (a la izquierda), y... dentro de ella debería estar el archivo `fpdf.php`, por supuesto. Y... tienes que tener en cuenta cómo poner la ruta en el `require`, como lo tienes ahora le estás indicando que, en la misma carpeta en la que está el script, busque una carpeta `fpdf` y dentro de ella el archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un problema de rutas.

Podrías indicarle al script que mire en la ruta que usas a ver si el fichero existe antes de intentar cargarlo, con **file_exists()**, y te devolvería false, ¿por que? no encuentra el fichero.

Aunque aparentemente la ruta esté correcta y el fichero esté ahí. Las rutas son relativas a la posición del primer fichero al que se accede al cargar la aplicación y no solo eso, los ficheros se cargan como si se estuvieran cargando desde ese fichero.

> Un ejemplo.

Tienemos una carpeta de proyecto con un "index.php" y el directorio "app", y dentro de este las carpetas "foo" y "baz", con los ficheros "foo.php" y "baz.php" en cada uno de ellos respectivamente. Es decir que tienes:

```
proyecto/index.php
proyecto/app/baz/baz.php
proyecto/app/foo/foo.php
```

y la aplicación tiene su punto de entrada en "index.php", que normalmente situariamos en el directorio "htdocs/" del servidor.

Contenido de los ficheros:

```
<?php
// index.php ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

echo "Soy 'index.php' <br>";

require "app/foo/foo.php";

/*** Fin contenido index.php ***/


<?php
// foo.php /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo "Soy 'foo.php' <br>";

$ruta1 = "../baz/baz.php";
$ruta2 = "../../baz/baz.php";
$ruta3 = "app/baz/baz.php";

if (file_exists($ruta1)) {
    echo "Cargando ruta 1... <br>";
    require $ruta1;
}

if (file_exists($ruta2)) {
    echo "Cargando ruta 2... <br>";
    require $ruta2;
}

if (file_exists($ruta3)) {
    echo "Cargando ruta 3... <br>";
    require $ruta3;
}

/*** Fin contenido foo.php ***/


<?php
// baz.php /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
echo "Soy 'baz.php' <br>";

/*** Fin contenido baz.php ***/
```

Si abres la página, la salida será:

```
Soy 'index.php' 
Soy 'foo.php' 
Cargando ruta 3... 
Soy 'baz.php'
```